# How do I enable multiple phone numbers for iMessge and FaceTime?

Tags: messages, facetime

I have a couple of active SIM cards in a couple of different countries. How can I set my phone up to receive iMessages and FaceTime calls from all those numbers, even though there's obviously only one SIM in my phone at once?

Comment: Please only answer if you have *done* this and made it *work*, I have tried all the obvious things and it just results in the number for the SIM that's not in the phone disappearing.

Comment: Hopefully someone is able to find something that works, but I'd be surprised if that's at all possible. iMessage (and Facetime) are clearly designed with one phone number in mind. This allows non-phone-number devices such as the Mac or iPad to sync messages across devices that were sent to a particular phone number.